# Prisma custom field attribute

Tags: prisma

I get the model's field:

```
Prisma.dmmf.datamodel.models
```

Filter the results, and I get an array of objects:

```
  {
    name: 'supplierOrders',
    kind: 'object',
    isList: true,
    isRequired: true,
    isUnique: false,
    isId: false,
    isReadOnly: false,
    hasDefaultValue: false,
    type: 'SupplierOrder',
    relationName: 'ProductToSupplierOrder',
    relationFromFields: [],
    relationToFields: [],
    isGenerated: false,
    isUpdatedAt: false
  },
```

I would like to add a custom key:value, like this:

```
  {
    name: 'supplierOrders',
    kind: 'object',
    ...
    customKey: "custom value"
  },
```